# What is the difference between Save.Press() and Actions.PressSave()?

Tags: acumatica

I created an action to "Complete" a record.  The action executes:

```
Actions.PressSave();

foreach(MyDAC record in Records)
{
    myRecord.Status = Statuses.Complete;
    this.MyView.Update(myRecord);
    Save.Press();  <--- 
}
```

When I used Actions.PressSave(); at the bottom of the code sample (see the <---) it errors out.  When I use Save.Press(); it works great.

What is the difference between the two?  (How would I decide the appropriate selection between the two?)

Comment: The difference between these two is that Save action can be added to the graph, but it may also be absent on the graph. Besides, one can create custom implementation of the save action on the graph. While PressSave is guaranteed to present on the graph and can't be easily customized. So, you can assume that PressSave provides same generic functionality for every graph.

Comment: Could you specify the error that you get when you try to execute PressSave()?

Comment: Could you provide more info about the graph you use? Is it a custom graph? Does it have Save button?

Comment: I did not save the message, but it was something like “record could not be saved”.  The graph is custom.  Since I updated the view as I did, the more proper save is probably to use Persist on the view as HB_Acumatica advised me on another question earlier, but I see these two forms of “save” in standard actions on standard graphs.  My graph is a custom entry screen, and I use the action to allow the user to “complete” the record, indicating that they have performed the necessary actions in the physical world that the record was there to instruct.  It DOES have the save button.

Comment: "The Site Says... Error: The record cannot be saved."  [link](http://prntscr.com/nfrtk4)

Comment: The 3 ways I know to execute a save programmatically are:  via the cache (1) this.Caches[typeof(DAC)].Update(myRecord); this.Caches[typeof(DAC)].Persist(PXDBOperation.Update); (2) Save.Press(); and (3) Actions.PressSave();  I normally use the 1st when I am updating a record outside of my current view, and the 2nd/3rd arbitrarily when I want to save the current graph via the save button.  The confusion is that Save.Press(); works in my current example, but not Actions.PressSave();  It makes sense that Save.Press() is the actual "save" since the Persist action in most menus ends up calling it.

Comment: For your example, Persist should be used inside the loop and at the end outside the loop you can call the Save action if necessary. Calling an action is an heavy operation, you want to avoid calling it multiple times if not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save.Press() is explicitly defined action on Graph. Actions.PressSave() is predefined graph action. Anyway, both will execute persist delegate.

Comment: Thanks.  Also important to note is Dmitry's comment about being able to create custom implementation of the save action on the graph.  The comment that pointed me to resolving the issue leading to my question was HB_Acumatica noting that the Save should be moved outside the loop on my example.